# copy /b command size limit issue

Tags: zip, concatenation

I am using `copy /b` command to append two diff files in one file. This command does not work if the first file is of size larger than 1 GB. I have not found any references or help online.

I am using this command:

```
copy /b file1+file2 outputfile
```

Actualy I am trying to embed a zip folder with some files in it and trying to append it with a file (which is more than 1 GB). 
like:

```
copy /b file1(large file)+zipfile outputfile
```

If file1 is less than 1 GB, I can open output file using WinRAR and can view the files that was previously in the zip folder.
but, in case if file1 is greater than 1 GB, the command says 1 file is copied, but when I choose to open output file using WinRAR it prompts that "No archives found". That's my major problem.

How do I solve this issue or is there a similar software solution for large files?

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with `copy /b`? Maybe it's WinRAR that doesn't look for archives past 1 GB.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I figured out that copy /b is really not the problem because i tried to concatenate filebytes using c# streams and that same issue is also with that. So is there any solution for the winrar problem?

Comment: Uhm, try 7-Zip? ;)